# angular carousel does not give the intended result

Tags: html, css, angular

I am developing a small angular application where I want to use an image carousel. I base myself on an example I found at this adress : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gallery-carousel-slider-dvh17w?file=package.json.

I reproduced the same in my application. Here is how I integrated it in my template :

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <div style="width:100%;" class="md-toolbar-tools" >
    Detail de l'annonce
    <span flex></span>
  </div>
</mat-toolbar>
<div fxLayout="row">
  <div fxFlex="20%"></div>
  <div fxFlex="60%">
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-content>
                    <div fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                        <!-- <img src="./../assets/image/image1.jpg" alt="Avatar" > -->
                        <app-carousel [autoPlayDuration]="5000" animation="slide" [isNavigationVisible]="true" [isThumbnailsVisible]="true" [slides]="slides"
                        [slideTemplateRef]="slide" [thumbnailTemplateRef]="thumbnail"></app-carousel>
                        <ng-template #slide let-slide>
                            <div [ngStyle]="{
                                    'background-size': 'cover',
                                    'background-image': 'url(' + slide.url + ')',
                                    'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
                                    'width': '100%',
                                    'height': '100%'
                                }">
                            </div>
                        </ng-template>
                        <ng-template #thumbnail let-slide>
                                <div [ngStyle]="{
                                        'background-size': 'cover',
                                        'background-image': 'url(' + slide.url + ')',
                                        'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
                                        'background-position': 'center center',
                                        'width': '100%',
                                        'height': '100%'
                                    }"></div>
                        </ng-template>                      
                    </div>
                    <hr color="blue" width="100%">
```

When I deploy my application and display the page on the browser with width=1200px, I obtain the following image

[image]

As you can see I have an issue with the height of the main image

When I reduce the width of the browser to width=960px, the height of the main image shrink even more:

[image]

As you can see I have an issue that degrades even more with the height of the main image

When I reduce the width of the browser to width=650px, the height of the main image shrink even more:

[image]

As you can see I have an issue that degrades even more with the height of the main image

When I reduce the width of the browser to width=564px, the height of the main image shrink even more, until disappear:

[image]

In summary, I have a big problem with the height of the main image (I would like that the height be proportional with the width), which degrades when I reduce the width of the browser. Could you give me a help so that the main image keep a proportional height with the width, and this, even when I reduce the width of the browser ? Thank you

Comment: Do you really want to use your own implementation of the carousel? Or you can use third-party ones like the ng-bootsrap one? If you still want it, can you please province your version of stackblitz?

Comment: Hello yazantahhan, On your suggestion, I chose a bootstrap carousel. One example is given at this adress. (https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-ng-bootstrap-carousel-tutorial/) Thank you